# How to transfer Google Notebooks over to Evernote?

Tags: evernote, migrate-data

I have a certain amount of notes in my [Google Notebook](http://google.com/notebooks). How do I transfer this data over to [Evernote](http://evernote.com/), without losing any meta information such as "tags"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the Evernote folks have [written](http://blog.evernote.com/2009/01/22/google-notebook-import-2/) something especially for this case:

1. Sign into Google Notebook
2. Click on a notebook that you want to export
3. Click the Export link at the bottom of the page
4. Choose ‘Atom’ from the export options.
5. Save the Google Atom Notebook file to your desktop

Then go over to https://www.evernote.com/GoogleNotebooks.action and just import the created "Atom".

Repeat for all notebooks.